# terminate a thread in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, terminate

How can I terminate a thread in a proper way?
When the thread finishes, it is still in memory. I'm using Delphi 2010 (Update 5).

Comment: Use the FreeOnTerminate property. When the thread terminates - it is Free'd :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I usually describe the issues of thread termination is to stress co-operation.  You should not terminate a thread. Instead you should notify the thread that you want it to terminate. You then politely wait until it has terminated.

The reasons for this are manifest. Only the thread knows how to terminate itself. Only the thread knows what locks it holds, what resources it needs to free etc.

The same arguments apply if you wish to pause or suspend a thread's execution. You should ask to it do so and then let the thread find a convenient moment when it is safe to do so.

With a Delphi `TThread` the standard way to request termination is to call `Thread.Terminate`. This does nothing more than to set a flag in the thread object. That is the request. The response is initiated by the thread code inside `TThread.Execute`. That should regularly check the value of its `Terminated` property. When that is found to be true, it should exit from the function. Naturally any tidy up (release locks, return resources etc.) should be performed before calling exit.

Comment: thanks david, 
but is this a bug?
and in other programming languages to stop programs similar method is used?

Comment: @Mohammad No it's not a bug, and no other system I know routinely kills threads in a pre-emptive manner.

Comment: Exactly. You don't KILL threads normally, you signal them. They close themselves.

Answer (score 3):

How exactly do you terminate a thread? If you just set Terminate, this is just a flag checked inside of the thread. If you need to terminate thread of execution (and not signal a TThread object that it needs to finish), you can use [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function. But you should notice that this leads to resource leaks (as written in the comments in documentation for TerminateThread).

Comment: Resource leaks are not the real reason for avoiding calls to TerminateThread. The real reason is that it is likely to deadlock your app when you terminate a thread which holds a lock.

Comment: When I use myThread.Terminate,  it is still in memory and running.

Comment: Terminate **does not* terminate the thread by itself - it just sets the Terminated property to true. You have to check for it in your Execute method (sometimes not in one place only) , and exit from the Execute method as soon as you can (after you cleaned up everything you need, usually). A thread terminates when the Execute method exits. Then the OS thread is terminated, but the TThread instance still exists. You have to free the instance, or use the FreeOnTerminate property (but be aware of what it implies).

Comment: TerminateThread() "kills" the thread with all what it implies. It means memory could not be released, handles are lost, locks are not released, and other issue explained in MSDN. All issues a developer would like to avoid.
It was not designed to be used as a common function to terminate a thread, it was designed to be used in exceptional situations.

Comment: @Mohammed Don't use TerminateThread. Don't use TerminateThread. Don't use TerminateThread. Don't use TerminateThread. Don't use TerminateThread. Don't use TerminateThread. Don't use TerminateThread.

Comment: So what I do?
What is the solution that the thread be stopped and resources are released?

Comment: @Mohammad I've answered the question in this comment with a full-blown answer because there's too much details for a plain comment.

Comment: @David not releasing the lock is a part of the effect of resources not being released.

Comment: @Eugene Agreed. But it's worth calling out explicitly because one often things of not releasing resources as just being memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

that depends on what you want to accomplish with that thread. you should provide more details about what you want to do, before we can help you.

here you have a very good tutorial on how to work with threads in Delphi:

http://www.eonclash.com/Tutorials/Multithreading/MartinHarvey1.1/Ch1.html

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Writing_multi-threaded_applications_Index

Comment: You can now use this link:http://www.nickhodges.com/MultiThreadingInDelphi/ToC.html